# Drawing unfilled rectangle shape in openGL

Tags: opengl

I want to draw unfilled rectangle shape in `OpenGL`, but when I used `glBegin(GL_QUADS)` or `glBegin(GL_POLYGON)`, the resulted shape is filled but I want to be unfilled. How I can draw unfilled rectangle.

```
void draweRect(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glLineWidth(30);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2i(50,90);
        glVertex2i(100,90);
        glVertex2i(100,150);
        glVertex2i(50,150);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();   
}
```

Comment: I guess just draw lines? Using 'GL_LINES'.

Comment: @DanSkeel : have a look at this : https://wiki.delphigl.com/index.php/glBegin

Comment: If you just draw lines, the points wont be all connected. He would only have 2 of 4 lines.

Answer (score 10):

Use `GL_LINE_LOOP` (instead of `GL_POLYGON`) to draw a connected series of line segments on the perimeter of your polygon rather than filling the polygon.

Alternatively, you could use `glPolygonMode (GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)`... remember to set it back to the default `glPolygonMode (GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL)` to resume usual (filled) rendering though.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the fill mode for your rendering.

You can use the [`glPolygonMode(...);`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml) method.

Try the following:

```
void draweRect(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glLineWidth(30);

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2i(50,90);
        glVertex2i(100,90);
        glVertex2i(100,150);
        glVertex2i(50,150);
    glEnd();

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

    glFlush();   
}
```

Comment: Not that it matters with all of the deprecated things being used here, but I would avoid using `GL_FRONT` as a general rule. GL 3.1 requires `GL_FRONT_AND_BACK`, it no longer allows per-side polygon modes. In case you were wondering, that is the reason it says only `GL_FRONT_AND_BACK` is valid in the linked reference page - that page is for GL4; the GL2 version can be found [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glPolygonMode.xml)

Answer (score 3):

This one worked for me..

```
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2f(x1,y1);
    glVertex2f(x2,y1);
    glVertex2f(x2,y2);
    glVertex2f(x1,y2);
glEnd();
```